# Likes and Dislike count for weekly data from YouTube Data API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is it possible to get the below data from YouTube Data API?

- Artist Channel Subscriber counts, by day
- Thumbs Up, Thumbs Down for YouTube Videos or by ISRC, by day
- Shares for YouTube Videos or by ISRC, by day

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't filter dates in Youtube Data API

In Youtube Data API :Channels

> A **`channel`** resource contains information about a YouTube channel.

To get Subscriber count, use:

> *statistics.subscriberCount*
>
> The number of subscribers that the channel has.

---

You can use Youtube Analytics and Reporting APIs, to create a concrete stats regarding subscriber count,likes or dislikes and shares read carefully the [dimension](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/dims) and [metrics](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/mets) for a good search query parameters.

## Metrics

> This document defines the metrics that you can retrieve using the YouTube Analytics API. This API supports real-time queries to generate custom YouTube Analytics reports.
>
> Metrics are individual measurements of user activity, ad performance, or earnings. User activity metrics include things like video view counts and ratings (likes and dislikes).

The list below identifies some of the API's core metrics.

- dislikes
- likes
- shares
- subscribersGained
- subscribersLost

## Dimensions

> This document defines the dimensions that the YouTube Analytics API supports. This API supports real-time, targeted queries to generate custom YouTube Analytics reports.
>
> Dimensions are common criteria that are used to aggregate data, such as the date on which user activity occurred or the country where users were located.
>
> Each query report identifies the dimensions that it supports. For example, when retrieving user activity by time, you choose the time period for which data will be reported: *day*, *7DayTotals*, *30DayTotals*, *month*. In any report, each row of data has a unique combination of dimension values.

## NOTE:

> *Core dimension* and *Core Metrics* is subject to the [Deprecation Policy](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube-api-list).

Unfortunately you have to use staticstics of Youtube Data API to get Subscriber counts, likesCount and dislikeCount. Hope it helps!

Comment: Mr.Rebot.. Hope this helps. :)